# Kanban Board with protagonists as employees

Tags: tools

In my professional life, I am a software engineer in a small agile company, and we use kanban boards to track the developers activities, like that:

[image: An exapmple of a kanban borad]

Succumbing to my latest urge in creative writing, I found out that it is very efficient to have something like that for a novel. Here, the novel itself is a project, and protagonists, places and even time periods are "employees" that are assigned to work on a "ticket", be it an "epic" (chapter) or a "bug" (sudden idea I shouldn't forget to fix in a revision), or whatever else.

I googled for creative writing software, or actually whatever software that will have this functionality. Unfortunately, the existing kanban boards are either for a single user where roles can't be given, or for teams of **real people**, that is, people with **valid emails** which they use to confirm their participation on the project.

There are lots of different creative writing tools, but I was wondering if anyone knows about a software that allows for a kanban board with virtual employees in the sense I've just described.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Email addresses are free, if that's the only thing holding you up...

Comment: Creating a bunch of fake e-mails is a dirty hack, and I am at odds at hacking my mind to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [gmail aliases](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/6-clever-gmail-tricks-to-minimize-regret-frustration-and-spam/#:%7E:text=Unlimited%20aliases%2C%20sort%20of&text=By%20simply%20adding%20a%20%2B%20to,giving%20it%20away%20to%20spammers.) would permit you to evaluate the process with a minimum of superfluous effort.  using the '+' sign and extending a legit gmail address to make it become mygmail+heroProtagonist@gmail.com and your villain mygmail+BaddyMcBadGirl@gmail.com and so on.

Then, if you find the Kanba board method helps you, then grabbing an open source implementation and modifying it to permit multiple people having the same address would be a great next solution.

Implementing servers aren't a barrier since they can be hosted on local machines in Virtual Box or on google and amazon cloud computing platforms for low to no cost -- for very anemic servers

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution, but it is not a clean solution as, again, it assumes you have to have many unnecessary redundancies. I have contacted my fellow proggers who may be interested in creating such a soft on our own.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly speaking a Kanban tool but I wonder whether you might be able to replicate what you're looking for using [Speare](https://www.speare.com/), it's not free sadly but there is a free trial so you could try it out and see if it does what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on GitHub and found [TaskBoard](https://github.com/kiswa/TaskBoard). It might meet your needs.

Comment: TaskBoard still requires setting up a server. Not that I'm incapable of doing this, but it still sounds like complying to rigidly imposed superfluous rules.